# How do I read this "for-loop" code from freecodecamp

Tags: javascript, for-loop, string-length, variable-length

this is basically the code, I already got the right answer but I'm just trying to figure out how the process work

> total = 20

```
   var myArr = [ 2,3,4,5,6];
    var total = 0;

    for (var d = 0; d < myArr.length; d++){
       total += myArr[d];

    }
```

and I did  this

```
   var myArr = [ 2,3,4,5,6];
var total = "";

for (var d = 0; d < myArr.length; d++){
   total += myArr;

}
```

the output is.... (total is =""; so I can see what's happening inside but..

> total= 2,3,4,5,62,3,4,5,62,3,4,5,6

and got confuse then I change the myArr to d

```
var myArr = [ 2,3,4,5,6];
var total = 0;

for (var d = 0; d < myArr.length; d++){
   total += d;

}
```

why is it

> total = 10?

Comment: strings aren't the same as numbers, and whole arrays aren't the same as individual items from arrays

Comment: When you declare the variable `total = "";` you're declaring it as a string, whereas when you say `total = 0;` you make it a number.
Therefore using the `+=` operation, in the first case you are adding strings, in the second you're actually adding numbers to numbers (it's called maths ;) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added comments to your working solution as below.

```
//Create new array to store our range
var myArr = [ 2,3,4,5,6];
//create new variable to store our total at the end
var total = 0;

//repeat code within when d < the length (or number of values) in our array, increment d each time it runs
for (var d = 0; d < myArr.length; d++){
   //take the current total and add the current value in our array to it each time
   // first time it will be 0 (total) + 2 (myArr[0]) second time it will be 2 (total) + 3 (myArr[1]) and so on.
   total += myArr[d];

}
```

As another user has pointed out in your second attempt you've changed the datatype of total from a number to a string.

Comment: Wow I didn't  see that, thank you everyone for the TIME and ATTENTION !!
also in this code..

`total =0; 

  total += [d];`


why is the answer =10?
it suppose to be like "answer " = 5? or 6

Comment: Are you asking why the value is 10? The reason is because you're adding the value of [d] which is your counter. The counter increases each time the loop is executed (note the d++), there are 5 items in your array so it would be looped 5 times, so it would look something like (0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4).

Comment: hylian thank  you so much man!!! love it!! ( love it mean's  your Time and Attention)
also so the answer  should be 5 or 6 not 10? 
I got learn so far is that  when you declaring a for loop operation  + .length the function excecute the same as the length which is about 4 or 5 item's so why is it 10? really sorry for asking this new beginner's question, just started  learning JS. for Alexa Skills..

Comment: @Spaceboard it would be 5 if it was written as total = [d]; so your counter 'd' is updated each time the loop is run with the end result of d being set to 5 as the loop as run 5 times. Because you have it as total += [d] it's taking the current value of total and adding D to it each time, so it would start off as 0, then it runs 1 time so total is now 1, then it's run 2 times so total is now 3 because 1+2 = 3, and so on. Does that make sense?

Comment: hylian!! wow lol I didn't even know what the += thanks  for the clarification, and hylian thanks for everything and I thing the small detail about += will help me solve this problem next " 5! = 1*2*3*4*5 = 120"


  `function factorialize(num) {
   var num1;
   for(num1 = 0; num1 <= num; num1++ * ++num1){

 return num1;

}
  
     
}

factorialize(5); `


 this is my code for now  but I think  using *= would solve it Hylian thank's  for everything and just amaze  how the universe work!!

you have a AWESOME of  Christmas dude.

Answer (score 0):

In the first instance:

```
var myArr = [ 2,3,4,5,6];
var total = 0;

for (var d = 0; d < myArr.length; d++){
    total += myArr[d];
}
```

You're creating a new variable outside the scope of the loop which is just 0.  As you loop through each iteration, you're adding the current index of the array (`myArr[d]`) to the `total` variable.

In your second one, you're creating a new variable that's an empty string.  JavaScript doesn't know or care that you're trying to add numbers, so it appends the number to an empty string, hence your result.

```
var myArr = [ 2,3,4,5,6];
var total = "";

for (var d = 0; d < myArr.length; d++){
  total += myArr;
}
```

The `+=` operator applies to strings as well as numbers, and behaves differently depending on what the values are.

```
0 + '1' - 2 + '-3' // "-1-3"
0 + '1' - 2 // -1
```